# Why it is throw error an "conflicting declarations: private final var binding: FragmentImageBinding? in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new in android Kotlin mobile apps development, I try to  use binding in my project, but when I type binding in project, it is throw an error as a

> Conflicting declarations: private final var binding:
> FragmentImageBinding?, private final val binding: [ERROR : Error
> function type]

any idea?

```
    private  var binding: FragmentImageBinding? = null
    private  val binding get() = binding!!

    private lateinit var recyclerViewImage: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        binding = FragmentImageBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        return binding.root
      }
```

**gradle:**

```
buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of that you have two variables with the same name,
this one:

```
private  var binding: FragmentImageBinding? = null
```

and this one:

```
private  val binding get() = binding!!
```

change first one name to _binding and your error will be solved!
Your code must be like this:

```
    private  var _binding: FragmentImageBinding? = null
    private  val binding get() = _binding!!

    private lateinit var recyclerViewImage: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        _binding = FragmentImageBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        return binding.root
      }
```

Comment: The whole point of the `binding` property is so you don't have to use `_binding!!` all over the place. You just need to be aware that it can only be safely used while the view is not destroyed, so don't use it in an asynchronous callback (other than view click listeners since they won't be clicked when destroyed).